# Mount a detachable LED strip to spokes of bike

Tags: embedded, hardware, pov

I have an LED strip and Arduino I have mounted onto the spokes of a bike using twist ties (like this: https://learn.adafruit.com/bike-wheel-pov-display/install-on-bike).  I want to make it detachable though and was wondering how to go about doing that?  I was thinking of attaching the LED strip and Arduino to a pvc pipe and using a clip to attach the pvc pipe to the spokes of the wheels.

Comment: The article you link to shows the use of *zip ties*, not twist ties. [Twist ties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_tie) are often found holding electrical cables neatly in new goods and would make it detachable. You can get releasable cable ties if you want something which may be stronger than a twist tie. Also, string is available.

Comment: IMO, zip ties _are_ detachable. You buy a 500pack of zip ties, when you need to detach you cut them, and when you need to re-attach, you use more zip ties.

Comment: Ah.  I was hoping to get something more permanent.  Like something that can be turned into a consumer product rather than a DIY project.

Comment: Since there are professionals here who contribute their time for free (I'm just a hobbyist), it would be considerate to clarify at the outset that you are looking for a commercial-ready solution. The question sounds a lot more like a hobby thing and it would be very easy to mistake purposes. Just good etiquette. (I don't care because it isn't my livelihood.)

Comment: @jonk That is a good point.  I'm not looking to mass produce or anything.  I think it would be cool to be able to sell them to people around the neighborhood (they would each be hand made).  The problem is it's hard to sell a product that can't be taken off once it's put on.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Be sure to take the tour to get the most out of this site:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour